# Error with yaml-cpp while trying to run file

Tags: c++, yaml-cpp

Im trying to run the sample file given here:

http://cpp-shuda.googlecode.com/svn-history/r12/trunk/Yaml/main.cpp

Ive copied everything as is, and i have the include folder setup in visual studio 2012. I'm getting:

```
IntelliSense: no operator ">>" matches these operands operand types are: const YAML::Node >> std::string c:\Users\...\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\Project\Project\qtproject.cpp
```

Comment: What version of yaml-cpp do you have installed? Also, the file you link to has multiple main() functions, so presumably you've only copied one of them?

Comment: i have the latest version installed(0.5.1). and yes ive copied only one of those functions which is the first one

Answer (score -1):

Those sample programs are for the older versions of yaml-cpp (0.3.x and below). For examples of how to use the new API, see the the [tutorial](https://code.google.com/p/yaml-cpp/wiki/Tutorial) on the project page.